# Iterate through terms in symbolic expression

Tags: function-construction, symbolic

I'm trying to define a linear function which acts on functions, but I'm having trouble when passing a sum of functions. Here's what I mean:

```
arg[_[x__]] := x
Fuse[T1_, T2_] := T[arg[T1] + arg[T2]] + T[arg[T1] - arg[T2]]
```

In other notation $T_{\alpha} \cdot T_{\beta} = T_{\alpha + \beta} + T_{\alpha - \beta}$.

My goal is to have a function which will act Fuse linearly over a sum, so that $T_{\alpha} \cdot (T_{\beta} + T_{\gamma})= T_{\alpha} \cdot T_{\beta} + T_{\alpha} \cdot T_{\gamma}$, i.e.

> Fuse[T[a1], T[b1] + T[b2]] = Fuse[T[a1], T[b1]] + Fuse[T[a1], T[b2]]

but because it's extracting the arguments it can only deal with single terms (what is the 'argument' of (T[a] + T[b]), or for that matter of 2T[a]?).

Is there a way to turn a sum of symbolic terms into a list that I can iterate through or in some way extract the argument of each term?

Comment: Does this do it? `Fuse[T1_, T2_ + T3_] := Fuse[T1, T2] + Fuse[T1, T3]`.

Comment: That does!! Bless function overloading. Now I just need to figure out how to strip coefficients (i.e. Fuse[ T1, 2 T2])

Comment: This worked: multiplying the first Fuse def by `Coefficient[T1, T[arg[T1]]]*Coefficient[T2, T[arg[T2]]]`. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @quixot Please summarize the solution you found in a self-answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march), the solution was to overload the function to take a sum, as well as adjusting the `arg` function to strip away coefficients and then put them back in the main `Fuse` function, like so:

```
arg[a_ T_[x__]] := x;

Fuse[T1_, T2_] := Coefficient[T1, T[arg[T1]]] * Coefficient[T2, T[arg[T2]]] * 
(T[arg[T1] + arg[T2]] + T[arg[T1] - arg[T2]]);

Fuse[T1_, T2_ + T3_] := Fuse[Expand[T1], Expand[T2]] + Fuse[Expand[T1], Expand[T3]]
```

The Expand was because the function didn't work when given sums inside brackets, e.g. `2(T[a] + T[b])` This gave me exactly what I wanted!